# jQuery - Create element and append to all links, except some

Tags: jquery

The style of the pages I'm building is to have a little triangle after each link.  As such, I've built a little script that appends a <span> after each link.

I'm creating a new span, with a class and appending it to all anchors, but I don't want it do to it in the nav anchors.

Of course, I can just hide the appended spansin css for those I don't want, but surely I can just tweak what I have:

```
$('<span/>',{
    'class': 'im'
    }).appendTo('a').not(".nav ul > li > a");
```

The not() part isn't working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
$('<span/>',{
    'class': 'im'
    }).appendTo($('a').not(".nav ul > li > a"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QX2wD/1/)

Comment: upvoted this one just because `.not()` is recommended usage over `:not`

Comment: Awesome. I knew it was simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `not` part should be in the `'a'` selector :

```
... 
.appendTo('a:not(.nav ul > li > a)')
```

I would suggest that you tag your `a` anchors somehow, to simplify the work of the selector, for example :

1. add a `navLink` class to `a`s in the `.nav` bar,
2. then your selector becomes `'a:not(.navLink)'`, and selecting the nodes will involve less work from jQuery